# Performing a map operation on a Map

Tags: elixir

What is the most idiomatic way of performing a map operation on a Map?

Two approaches come to mind:

```
Enum.reduce(%{a: 1, b: 2}, %{}, fn({k,v}, acc) -> Map.put(acc, k, v+1) end)
# => %{a: 2, b: 3}

for {k,v} <- %{a: 1, b: 2}, do: {k, v+1}, into: %{}
# => %{a: 2, b: 3}
```

Is there a better alternative that i haven't thought of? If not, which one of the above is preferred?

Comment: I think the second option is not that bad.

Comment: There's also `:maps.map/2` which might be more efficient than either of these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd instinctively go for the `Enum.map` approach:

```ruby
input
  |> Enum.map(fn{k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end)
  |> Map.new()
```

It makes your intention clear, it's easy to read, it will work for all `Enum`s and should be OK performance-wise.

When it comes to performance, `Enum.map/2` is your second choice after `:maps.map/2` suggested by Dogbert:

```
##### With input Large   (100 0000 items) #####
Name                        ips        average  deviation         median
:maps.map                104.52        9.57 ms     ±9.91%        9.38 ms
Enum.map                  54.07       18.49 ms     ±8.32%       18.41 ms
Stream.map                44.33       22.56 ms    ±14.86%       22.50 ms
Enum.reduce               25.39       39.38 ms    ±22.03%       37.61 ms
for comprehension         25.01       39.99 ms    ±20.95%       37.30 ms

Comparison:
:maps.map                104.52
Enum.map                  54.07 - 1.93x slower
Stream.map                44.33 - 2.36x slower
Enum.reduce               25.39 - 4.12x slower
for comprehension         25.01 - 4.18x slower
```

The relative performance of the different approaches depends on the size of the input map, but `Enum.map` is always the second fastest option (at least on my machine).

Here's the code for the benchmark, using [Benchee](https://github.com/PragTob/benchee):

```ruby
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Benchmark.MapMap do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_args) do
    inputs = %{
      "Tiny    (10 items)"      => produce_map(10),
      "Small   (100 items)"      => produce_map(100),
      "Medium  (10 000 items)"     => produce_map(10_000),
      "Large   (100 0000 items)"    => produce_map(100_000),
    }

    Benchee.run(%{
      "Enum.reduce" =>
        fn(input) ->
          Enum.reduce(input, %{}, fn({k,v}, acc) -> Map.put(acc, k, mapper(v)) end)
        end,
      "for comprehension" =>
        fn(input) ->
          for {k,v} <- input, do: {k, mapper(v)}, into: %{}
        end,
      ":maps.map" =>
        fn(input) ->
          :maps.map(fn(_k, v) -> mapper(v) end, input)
        end,
      "Enum.map" =>
        fn(input) ->
          input
            |> Enum.map(fn{k, v} -> {k, mapper(v)} end)
            |> Map.new()
        end,
      "Stream.map" =>
        fn(input) ->
          input
            |> Stream.map(fn{k, v} -> {k, mapper(v)} end)
            |> Map.new()
        end
    }, [time: 1, warmup: 1, inputs: inputs])
  end

  def mapper(x), do: x + 1

  defp produce_atom(idx) do
    idx = Integer.to_string(idx)
    String.to_atom("a" <> idx)
  end

  defp produce_map(size) do
    1..size
      |> Enum.map(fn(i) -> {produce_atom(i), i} end)
      |> Map.new
  end
end
```

Side note: There's [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2), which does both the map creation and the transformation of the Enum values into map keys and  values, so you can have a similar approach without `Enum.map`.

Comment: Maps change their underlying data structure at 32 elements. It would be interesting to see benchmarks just under/above that limit.

Comment: `:maps.map` is what i was looking for. Too bad you have to wrap it manually to use it in a Elixir Pipeline.

Comment: Oh and you lose the ability to modify the key, if that is desired. I will probably go with `Enum.map` then. Thank you for the feedback and benchmark!